# Setting code as an atribute when calling a method

Tags: java, lwjgl

This is how i call a method:

```
initButton(0, 0, 150, 50, "button.png", "PNG");
```

This is the method:

```
private void initButton(float x, float y, float width, float height, String imageFileName, String imageFileType) {
    buttonImages.add(loadResClass.loadTextures(imageFileType, imageFileName));
    buttonFloats.add(new Vector4f(x, y, width, height));
    float mouseX = Mouse.getX();
    float mouseY = Mouse.getY() - Display.getHeight();
    if(mouseY < 0){
        mouseY = mouseY * -1;
    }

    if(mouseX > x && mouseY > y && mouseX < x+width && mouseY < y+height){ 
        //do something
    }
}
```

when calling initButton i want to set some code as an argument (or do something similar) and than put the code in initButton method instead of `//do something` comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [Strategy Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) to configure some behavior at run time. The method will take a strategy object as parameter. For example:

```
private void initButton(float x, float y, float width, float height, String imageFileName, String imageFileType, Strategy strategy) {
    // ...

    if(mouseX > x && mouseY > y && mouseX < x+width && mouseY < y+height){ 
        strategy.doWork();
    }
}
```

And call like this:

```
initButton(0, 0, 150, 50, "button.png", "PNG", new SpecificStrategy());
```

Answer (score 0):

If Swing, you can pass in an ActionListener or better an AbstractAction. If some other GUI library, then pass in a Runnable, or Future, or some other interface that allows you to inject code.

What library is this for?

**Edit 1**
You state:

> I'm not using any gui library.

But surely you are, whether it be Swing, or Android, or somesuch, otherwise how can you interact with the user?

**Edit 2**
You state:

> I'm not using any GUI libraries. I draw quads with LWJGL

Then perhaps you want to use a `Runnable` in this situation. Although I'm not sure how you are going to listen to mouse position...

Comment: I'm not using any GUI libraries. I draw quads with LWJGL

Comment: can you tell me more about them? This should be an anwser :D

Comment: @Chorche: It won't work. You are needing some type of mouse listener, not some code that will be called once. You will have to see if the lwjgl library has tools for this.